# Missing implementation of interface method IControl

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors

On XE2 it compiles without problems, on XE5 shows up these errors:

```
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetIsFocused
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetEnabled
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetAbsoluteEnabled
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetPopupMenu
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.EnterChildren
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.ExitChildren
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.DoActivate
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.DoDeactivate
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.MouseClick
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetInheritedCursor
    FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.SetAcceptsControls
```

Whole FMX.HintManager.pas code is here:
http://pastebin.com/XSfahpV0

Line 79 is:

```
THintItem  = class;
```

Anyone could help and tell what exactly should be added so it would be possible to compile?
If needed, I could provide with TeamViewer session.

Code is made to use Hints in FireMonkey, but seems none is updating it for long. 
Full source code is taken from Delphipraxis.

Regards,
G

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the compiler tells you what is up. You just have to learn how to decode its error messages. Here is how to do it.

Let's look at the first error:

> FMX.HintManager.pas(79): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IControl.GetIsFocused

This first of all points to line 79. Which reads:

```
THintItem  = class;
```

So the issue is with `THintItem`. Now this is a little confusing because this is a forward declaration. The real issue is discovered further down the unit, but the compiler always points the finger at where it believes the class declaration starts. And that's the forward declaration. So, whenever you encounter an error at a forward declaration, move forward to the actual declaration. Which is:

```
THintItem = class(TFmxObject, IControl)
```

So, that's a class derived from `TFmxObject` that implements the `IControl` interface. Now, the error message tells us that the class is missing an *implementation of interface method IControl.GetIsFocused*. Well, the compiler is of course right. There is no such method. And all the other errors are of the same nature, for all the other missing functions.

So, to solve the problem you will need to provide implementations of all the methods in `IControl`. The issue is no doubt that the FMX framework has changed extensively since its initial release with XE2, which was FMX v1, and the release that ships with XE5 which is FMX v3. You need to study and understand the differences in the framework, and port this code from FMX v1 to FMX v3.

Having taken a quick look at `THintItem`, it seems that most of the implementations of the `IControl` methods are null. For instance:

```
function THintItem.GetAcceptsControls: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

function THintItem.GetCursor: TCursor;
begin
  Result := crNone;
end;

function THintItem.GetDesignInteractive: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

procedure THintItem.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
end;

procedure THintItem.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
end;

procedure THintItem.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
end;

procedure THintItem.MouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
end;
```

So, your starter for ten would be to add empty or stub implementations for each of the missing methods. For instance:

```
function THintItem.GetIsFocused: boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

procedure THintItem.MouseClick(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
end;
```

You should then study the framework a little more closely to work out whether any of the methods need more than these stubs.

Comment: One example for one of those how to implement would help more. :)

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that this is not helpful

Comment: It is more than nothing, just not what i expected :)

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: example how would look implementation for atleast one of "Missing implementation of interface method IControl.*" in that code.

Comment: Why can't you do that? Are you struggling with the syntax of writing a method? I'm having a hard time knowing what you are stuck on.

Comment: I have no idea how should it be done. Thats why asking example.

Comment: Which part don't you get? The syntax? Or the FMX to FMX3 port?

Comment: The FMX to FMX3 part.

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question about that? I think I answered this one.

Comment: Please indicate the part of the question where you said that.

Comment: example how would look implementation for atleast one of "Missing implementation of interface method IControl.*" in that code. – Goaul 13 hours ago

Comment: That wasa comment after I answered

Comment: Didnt know you cant see all the conversation/spam. :)

Comment: The site is question and answer. You ask a question, and we try to answer. You can certainly ask for clarification in comments, but at some point it becomes a new question. To give you more help I now need to read the source code for FMX and FMX3. Quite a lot of effort. I trust you've already tried. Before I go on, please tell me what you found when you did this, so that I don't repeat what you have already done. Please don't tell me that you did not consult the source already.

Comment: OK, so how is that now? Is that more *helpful*?

Comment: You've gone quiet now. Do you have what you need?

Comment: So what i did reviewed changes in versions:
XE3: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Introducing_the_FireMonkey_Library
XE4: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE4
XE5: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5

Its still much to check, but till now didnt saw what I was looking for.

Mby there someone who can else see this issue and is more familiar with FM changes/delphi?